# HDD space disappearing on Windows

Tags: windows, hard-drive, disk-space

I have a Windows Server 2008, which has a 300GB HD. It has been running fine for a number of years. However recently it ran out of space. 
When investigating i ran a tool (WinDirStat) to see where disk space is used. It reported 60GB worth of files on the drive. 
Where is all the other space gone? I don't have shadow copy enabled.
I have cleaned up some space. And the then the next day the disk is full again. 
Some background:
I did have disk mirroring setup, and recently one of the drives died. I disabled mirroring.

Comment: Normally we tell people to use, WinDirStat, to determine that.  What were your findings?

Comment: If the space usage can't be otherwise accounted for, run `chkdsk /f` on the drive to repair file system problems.

Comment: use TreeSizeFree (and run it as admin): http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/